# Assign one array values into another one array in for loop in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
$arr1 = Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 0
)
$arr2 = Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 1
)
```

I want to create a new array with the values of a2 as keys in $arr1. My resultant array should be like this

```
$arr3 = Array
(
    [0] => $arr1 = Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 0
)
    [1] => $arr2 = Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 1
)
)
```

Note : All are in a for loop. Plz help me..

Comment: How does your example reflect the statement that you expect the values of the second array to be the keys in the first array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr3= array($arr1, $arr2);
```

It is simple.